# GLvideoFrame with MP4 file

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, avfoundation

I want to display a video frame buffer on a OpenGLES texture.
I have download and read the GLVideoFrame sample from apple.
It's great code, but i don't understand how it's possible to modify this code for use a movie file instead of video device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AVAssetReader to read frames from a file.